# How can I redirect to logon.jsp with unencrypted password in the HTTPSession?

Tags: security, authentication, jsp, session, jakarta-ee

I have a j2ee web app that is using JAAS form based authentication. However, due to some unusual requirements, I cannot have the user enter their username and password directly into the logon.jsp form and have them submit it. Instead, I must gather the data on a separate page, and then later redirect to logon.jsp to log them in.

What I am thinking of doing is storing the username/password unencrypted in the HTTPSession. When I am ready to authenticate, I use a response.redirect to route to logon.jsp. In logon.jsp, I take the username and password out of the Session, populate the standard 'j-security-check' form, and then use javascript to submit the form.

How much of a security hole is this? I'm uncomfortable routing the request to go to logon.jsp via the browser (thats what a redirect does) because someone might get access to the session, and therefore the unencrypted password. If I am using HTTPS / SSL, is this a likely situation? How would it be exploited?

I looked into invoking the login servlet directly in a JSP without using the form, but that doesn't seem to be a viable option, particularly because I lose my insulation from differing J2EE containers/application servers.

Anyone got any idea how I can limit this security hole? Would using forward as opposed to redirect be better, because it doesnt go back to the browser?

How bad is this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that its very easy to describe this kind of practice as horrific, but a lot more difficult to explain *why* it is horrific, or how it might be exploited in a situation where SSL is used. We place our sensitive information in the hands of HTTPS / SSL all the time, I dont see how this is any different.

Best practice would be to avoid interactions with the browser when unnecessary. You have to manage the pay off between security and usibility, asses your applications requirements and sensitivity, and act accordingly.

In any eventuality, using a forward as opposed to a redirect will prevent the browser participation, as a forward is performed internally on the web tier.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're sending the password back to the user so that the user can re-submit the form to the real login.jsp.  That sounds Battlefield Earth horrific to me.  Assuming the user types in the password after he types in the username, can the password form not simply submit directly to the login handler?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The 'user' isnt resubmitting the form in that they dont click submit, but a javascript would automatically submit the logon.jsp form after i had populated it with the values taken from the session. So the browser is doing it. Is that what you meant? The password form cannot submit directly to the login handler, that is exactly where my problem lies.

Comment: You condemn the approach strongly. Can you describe the steps an attacker would take to exploit it?

Answer (score -1):

Oh god. First rule of password security is never transmit a password in plaintext, ever. If you're storing it in the session in plaintext, that means you're probably having the password sent from the user to your server in plaintext (unless you're using SSL which I *strongly* suggest). This means any packet sniffer can find the password. As for storing them in the session in plaintext, that means you're vulnerable to session hijacking.

In other words. It is **horrific**. Do not do this.

Comment: Storing a password in plaintext in the session does not imply that SSL is not used. That's an unwarranted assumption.

Comment: Good point, I neglected to ask. However they're still vulnerable to session hijacking. I updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: I'll use SSL, and the password will encrypted in the web tier before being sent to the server, and it'll be encrypted in the database (one direction with salt). The only time it is in plain text is when i have to route to logon.jsp (it has to be submitted in plain text, WELL, if, despite the SSL, this is as horrific as you think, encrypting it when redirecting is my only option, but this will lead to a real headache). How bad is the response.redirect with the plaintext password in the session if im using SSL? How would this be exploited?